# Should count of resource be fetched in same API or separate API?

Tags: rest, api, http, api-design

We have data for cars i.e.

```
MakeId | ModelId | VersionId | Price
```

A single make can have multiple models and a single model can have multiple versions. Like BMW is a make, X3 is one of BMW's model AND '320d M Sport' is one of X3's version. We have created API to fetch all the cars like:

```
/api/cars/ => returns all the versions (hence all the cars).

/api/cars/?price=5-10 => returns versions with price range between 5 to 10 million.

/api/cars/?modelid=1 => returns all car/version which have 1 as their modelId.
```

With each of above API calls that returns back the version based on filter, we also need two things:

1. count of the cars fetched in the result i.e. that would be count of versions fetched in above API queries.
2. count of the distinct modelid fetched in the result of above queries.

How should we design APIs for this i.e. should the above 2 counts be returned back with the same API call that returns the version list OR these should be separate API calls?

Comment: it should be based on different criteria, do you want to display these counts  in the same page where you're calling your original API method you want to merge with

Comment: yes, for now requirement is to show these counts on the same page

Comment: are you going to do a lot of joins in the database side to bring such counts returned with your original API call, if so and in case you can do this as a simple call like (select count(*) from versions) you could separate it in a different call